# Python Tkinter Frame flashing with Scrollbar

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, frame, tkinter-canvas

I'm attempting to create a level selection menu of sorts for a terminal-based game I'm making. I had it sorting levels into columns of ten, but it occured to me that the menu would get very wide as more levels are added. Instead, I'm trying to make an alphabetical list that can be scrolled through.

I've followed several posts' advice about making a scrollable frame, and I've run into a problem I haven't seen before: The window keeps flashing and spazzing out. It only occurs one I add the line indicated below, but that line *also* is the one that makes the level buttons appear.

```
def show_levels(self, frames):
    self.menu_title = tk.Label(self,
                               text="  Nonstop Robot  ",
                               fg="blue"
                               )
    if frames:
        self.frame_levels = tk.Frame(self,
                                     relief="sunken",
                                     width=50,
                                     height=100
                                     )
        self.level_canvas = tk.Canvas(self.frame_levels)
        self.level_list = tk.Frame(self.level_canvas)
        self.level_scroll = tk.Scrollbar(self.frame_levels,
                                         orient="vertical",
                                         command=self.level_canvas.yview
                                         )
        self.level_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.level_scroll.set)
        self.frame_menu = tk.Frame(self)

    def level_bind(event):
        self.level_canvas.configure(
            scrollregion=self.level_canvas.bbox("all"),
            width=70,
            height=200
            )
    self.level_buttons = []
    """
    Code that adds the buttons to all the frames.
    """
    for b in self.level_buttons:
        b.pack()
    if frames:
        self.level_scroll.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.level_canvas.pack(side="left")
        self.level_canvas.create_window((0, 0),
                                        window=self.frame_levels,
                                        anchor="nw"
                                        )
        self.frame_levels.bind("<Configure>", level_bind)
        self.frame_levels.pack(side="bottom")
        self.level_list.pack()  # This is the line in question
        self.frame_menu.pack(side="top")
    self.menu_title.pack()
```

I removed the code that actually creates all the buttons, since it's very long. If needed, I can add it.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please provide a [mcve] as opposed to some method definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use both `create_window` and `pack` on `self.frame_levels`, and if you use `self.frame_levels.pack`, it will not scroll along with the rest of the canvas.

You also seem to have the problem that you create a canvas that is a child of `self.frame_levels`, and then later you try to add `self.frame_levels` to the canvas.